# How to use dentry_path_raw()

Tags: c, string, linux-kernel

I'm writing a kernel module for Linux whose purpose necessitates that absolute paths be derived from `dentry` structs. I know that the function `char *dentry_path_raw(struct dentry *dentry, char *buf, int buflen)` can be used to retrieve absolute paths from `dentry` structs. My problem is is that I do not know how to use it.

The buffer is supposedly where the path will be stored, but it wants a length for the buffer. How am I supposed to know what the length should be without having the full path to begin with?

I'm going to need to compare the path it gets with several hardcoded pathnames, but how do I do that with a buffer? Would this work:

```
char *path_of_file = dentry_path_raw(my_dentry, my_buffer, buflen);
char *test_path = "/root/file";
if (path_of_file == test_path) {
    return 0;
} else {
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Oh my... Never compare C strings like this, you are basically comparing addresses to strings, rather than strings content. Use `strcmp()` to do real comparing. I propose you to learn C language first, before getting to kernel development.

Comment: @SamProtsenko It's better than using the kernel's `strncmp` which only compares sections of strings.

Comment: No, it's not, because result of such a comparison will be **always** false... And actually **there is** regular `strcmp()` in kernel: see [this](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/lib/string.c#L225).

Answer (score 4):

```
path = dentry_path_raw(dentry, buffer, buflen);
```

builds path from the end `buffer` to the beginning. That is, `buffer[buflen - 1]` is set to '\0' and resulted `path` pointer will be greater or equal to `buffer`.

> How am I supposed to know what the length should be without having the full path to begin with?

Even function itself doesn't know length of the path until it fully writes it. Just pick buffer with some lenght and call function. Good guess for path length would be `PATH_MAX`. If function found length to be insufficient, it returns error code `ERR_PTR(-ENAMETOOLONG)`.

As for path comparision, simple `strcmp(path, test_path)` can be used. If you know length of the `test_path`, you can compare it with length of `path`, which can be simply calculated, and then use memcmp:

```
if(test_path_len == ((buffer + buflen - 1) - path)
    && !memcmp(path, test_path, test_path_len)) // paths are equal
```

Note, that `dentry_path_raw` return path of the dentry relative to mount point of filesystem, contained this dentry. So, it will be absolute path only when dentry is contained by root filesystem.

Comment: So how can I get one that returns the actual full path?

Comment: `buffer` is a string, not a number, so it cannot be used in the path length comparison.

Comment: @Melab: `buffer + buflen -1` is *arithmetic on pointer*, which returns pointer to the last character in the buffer(which will be '\0'). Substracting `path` pointer from this one gives *distance* between last character in buffer and beginning of the path, that is actual length of path.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Do you know an alternative for `dentry_path_raw`  to get the *absolute* path of the dentry?